# How to link functions in form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I try to do that the func Form1_Load will display the city list.
I dont know how can i link the 3 functions of the cities (JerusalemData(), LondonData(), OttawaData()) to the function FillCitiesData();
The problem is that it doesnt show the list but only the streets without  choosing a city. Another problem - in HouseNum_ValueChanged it doesnt show numbers and you can also type letters and not just numbers.
This is my code - I'll be happy if anyone can help me find the problem.

```
namespace PlanYourParty
{

    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        List <City> cities;
        List <string> streets;

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            FillCitiesData();
        }

        public void FillCitiesData()
        {
            cities = new List<City>();
            cities.Add(new City() { Code = "123", Name = "Jerusalem" });
            cities.Add(new City() { Code = "456", Name = "London" });
            cities.Add(new City() { Code = "789", Name = "Ottawa" });
            JerusalemData();
            LondonData();
            OttawaData();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            FillCitiesData();
            cmbCity.DataSource = cities;
            cmbCity.DisplayMember = "Name";
            cmbCity.ValueMember = "Code";
            cmbCity.SelectedIndexChanged += cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged;
        }


        public void JerusalemData()
        {
            streets = new List<string>();
            cmbStreet.Items.Clear();
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Admond Peleg");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Pardes");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Nayman");
        }

        public void LondonData()
        {
            streets = new List<string>();
            cmbStreet.Items.Clear();
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Oxford Street");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Piccadilly");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Highfield Ave");
        }

        public void OttawaData()
        {
            streets = new List<string>();
            cmbStreet.Items.Clear();
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Riverside Drive");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Ontario Highway");
            cmbStreet.Items.Add("Moodie Drive");
        }

        private void cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != null && sender as City != null)
            {
                string code;
                code = (sender as City).Code;
                if (code == "123")
                {
                    JerusalemData();
                }
                else if (code == "456")
                {
                    LondonData();
                }
                else OttawaData();

            }

        }


        private void cmbStreet_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void domainUpDownHouseNumber_SelectedItemChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void Form1_Load_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

    }
```

Comment: That street data belongs inside the respective City objects. Make actual named variables for each city, and add a `List<String> Streets` property inside your City object definition. Then you can store that data in there instead of plugging it straight into the combo box. Then you can just get the data out of the selected object in `cmbCity_SelectedIndexChanged`. And in that function, assign `sender as City` to a variable, so you can use its properties more easily.

Answer (score 0):

First I suggest you separate your data model from the UI. Pull everything you need to define cities and streets in the `City` class. I have included two methods that return the cities in the example, and the streets for each city.

No need for *separate* methods that do the same thing, but with different data.

### City.cs

```
public class City
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public IList<string> Streets { get => GetStreets(this); }

    public static List<City> GetCities()
    {
        var cities = new List<City>();
        cities.Add(new City() { Code = "123", Name = "Jerusalem" });
        cities.Add(new City() { Code = "456", Name = "London" });
        cities.Add(new City() { Code = "789", Name = "Ottawa" });
        return cities;
    }

    public static List<string> GetStreets(City city)
    {
        var streets = new List<string>();
        if (city == null) return streets;
        switch (city.Code)
        {
            case "123":
                streets.Add("Admond Peleg");
                streets.Add("Pardes");
                streets.Add("Nayman");
                break;
            case "456":
                streets.Add("Oxford Street");
                streets.Add("Piccadilly");
                streets.Add("Highfield Ave");
                break;
            case "789":
                streets.Add("Riverside Drive");
                streets.Add("Ontario Highway");
                streets.Add("Moodie Drive");
                break;
            default:
                throw new ArgumentException("Unknown city code.");
        }
        return streets;
    }
}
```

Then write the UI such that the controls contain the lists of items as specified by the `City.GetCities()` and `City.GetSreets()` methods.

The currently selected city and street are returned by `CurrentCity` and `CurrentStreet` as well as their corresponding index in the combobox in `CurrentCityIndex` and `CurrentStreetIndex`.

### Form1.cs

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    protected override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);

        cityComboBox.DataSource = City.GetCities();
        cityComboBox.DisplayMember = nameof(CurrentCity.Name);
        cityComboBox.ValueMember = nameof(CurrentCity.Code);
        cityComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += CityComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
        cityComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;    // remove default selection of 1st item.

        streetComboBox.DataSource = Array.Empty<string>();
        streetComboBox.SelectedIndexChanged += StreetComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged;
    }

    private void CityComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Things when a city is selected.
        streetComboBox.DataSource = CurrentCity?.Streets;
        streetComboBox.SelectedIndex = -1;  // remove default selection of 1st item.
        UpdateLabels();
    }

    private void StreetComboBox_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // TODO: Things when a street is selected.
        UpdateLabels();
    }

    public void UpdateLabels()
    {
        cityInfo.Text = CurrentCityIndex >= 0 ? $"#{CurrentCity.Code} {CurrentCity.Name}" : "Please select a city.";
        streetInfo.Text = CurrentStreetIndex >= 0 ? CurrentStreet : "Please select a street.";
    }

    public List<City> AllCities { get => cityComboBox.DataSource as List<City>; }
    public List<string> AllStreets { get => streetComboBox.DataSource as List<string>; }

    public int CurrentCityIndex { get => cityComboBox.SelectedIndex; }
    public int CurrentStreetIndex { get => streetComboBox.SelectedIndex; }

    public City CurrentCity { get => cityComboBox.SelectedItem as City; }
    public string CurrentStreet { get => streetComboBox.SelectedItem as string; }
}
```

### Screen Shots

[image: scr1]

[image: scr2]